# How to read and write to file in C++ using eclipse on Mac

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, read-write, eclipse-mars

I am having a strange issue here. I have a file named input.txt, I want to read the lines in that file and and write it in to a file named useroutput.txt. I could able to do it in Windows using Visual C++. Am currently using eclipse because Visual C++ is not working on mac. The out file is successfully created, but there is no reading of lines or write in to the file is being done. I am bit new to C++. Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

The following is my code

```
#include <iostream>
# include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double saleAmount =0;
double ticketPrice;
int ticketsSold;

int totalTicketsSold = 0;

ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;

inFile.open("inputstadium.txt");
outFile.open("UserOutput.txt");

outFile<<fixed<<showpoint<<setprecision(2);

cout << "Processing data" << endl;

//1st row
inFile >> ticketPrice >> ticketsSold;
saleAmount = saleAmount + ticketPrice*ticketsSold;
totalTicketsSold = totalTicketsSold + ticketsSold;

//2nd row
inFile >> ticketPrice >> ticketsSold;
saleAmount = saleAmount + ticketPrice*ticketsSold;
totalTicketsSold = totalTicketsSold + ticketsSold;

//3rd row
inFile >> ticketPrice >> ticketsSold;
saleAmount = saleAmount + ticketPrice*ticketsSold;
totalTicketsSold = totalTicketsSold + ticketsSold;

//4th row
inFile >> ticketPrice >> ticketsSold;
saleAmount = saleAmount + ticketPrice*ticketsSold;
totalTicketsSold = totalTicketsSold + ticketsSold;

outFile << "Number of Tickets sold = " << totalTicketsSold<<endl;
outFile << "saleAmount = $ " << saleAmount<< endl;

inFile.close();
outFile.close();

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Did you check that the input file stream is actually opened? Is it where the program expects it to be? Is it where *you* expect it to be? Note that when running a program in an IDE the programs working directory is often the project root directory, not where the executable file is generated, you should check that (it's configurable) and make sure the input file is where the program expects it to be.

Comment: Also, on Windows `"inputstadium.txt"` and `"InputStadium.txt"` names the same file. On other systems they might be two different files.

Comment: Yeah my file is in the root folder. I dont know why the file is not readed and write it into the newfile. Checked the file names all correct